# How to implement if statement with BeautifulSoup and Selenium

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Not all eBay listings are the same because some pages use different format than others. I want my code to find the "price" element and if it doesn't exist, then try a different approach.  I created the code below but I was wondering what is a better method?

```
    item = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="prcIsum"]').text.strip().split()
    if len(item.text) > 0:
        price = item.text
    item = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mm-saleDscPrc"]')
    if len(item.text) > 0:
        price = item.text
    else:
        price = ""
```

[Entire Code](https://pastebin.com/dYbZAJ51)

Comment: Maybe you want to use the eBay API instead of scraping their HTML?

Comment: On Selenium it may raise error when object doesnt exists so you may have to use `try/except` to catch it. In other modules `xpath()` may gives empty list or `None` so you have to check it before you get `.text`

Comment: @Tomalak, I am avoiding API because I'm trying to learn webscrapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Selenium` it will raise error if element doesn't exists so you would have to use try/except

```
import selenium.webdriver

url = 'https://toscrape.com/'
url = 'http://books.toscrape.com/'

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

try:
    item = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tag').text.strip()
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
    try:
         item = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a').text.strip()
    except Exception as ex:
         print(ex)
         item = ''

print(item)
```

With `BeautifulSoup` you can get `None` (or empty list) so you have to check it before you get text.

```
import selenium.webdriver

url = 'https://toscrape.com/'
url = 'http://books.toscrape.com/'

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

soup = BS(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')


item = soup.find('tag')
if item:
    item = item.get_text(strip=True)
else:
    item = soup.find('a')
    if item:
        item = item.get_text(strip=True)
    else:
        item = ''

print(item)
```

Or you could try to get text inside `ttry/except`